# Mapnik and GeoTIFF tiling optimization

Tags: gdal, tiles, mapnik, optimization

If I am using one extra large GeoTiff as datasource.
Does Mapnik take advantage of tiled structure of source file (its a GeoTiff with internal tile structure) when rendering tiles? Which driver/plugin I should use to ensure that?
Raster or Gdal?

Answer (score 1):

Use [gdaladdo](http://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html) before render image.